# Adding ListBoxItems in Code-behind

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, listbox, microsoft-metro

How do we add new items to a ListBox control in a Windows Metro style application at run-time?

I come from WinForms, so as you could imagine, I'm pretty confused right now.

I have the following:

```
public class NoteView
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string b { get; set; }
   public string c { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
List<NoteView> notes = new List<NoteView>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   notes.Add(new NoteView {
      a = "text one",
      b = "whatevs",
      c = "yawns"
   });

   NotesList.ItemsSource = notes;
}
```

Which is useless. It does nothing. Also, there is nothing in the Output window. No errors, no exceptions; nothing.

So, then I tried directly adding to the ListBox:

```
NotesList.Items.Add("whatever!");
```

Again, nothing happened. So then I tried adding `UpdateLayout();` but that didn't help either.

Anybody know what's up with that?

How do we add new items to a XAML ListBox?

## Update:

```
        <ListBox Name="NotesList" Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: check out this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/listbox-in-wpf/     &  http://mmillies.wordpress.com/2008/07/12/wpf-binding-an-array-of-objects-to-a-listbox/

Comment: @COLDTOLD thank you; my XAML has been added to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to do it:

`notes.Insert(0, new NoteView { a = "Untitled note", b = "", c = "" });`

Answer (score 1):

YOu will have to do it a bit differently, you cannot just asign all the properties to listBox.
So create this kind of class:

```
 public class NoteView
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this is then the code inside button click event:

```
        List<NoteView> notes = new List<NoteView>();
        notes.Add(new NoteView { Item = "a", Value = 1 });
        notes.Add(new NoteView { Item = "b", Value = 2 });
        notes.Add(new NoteView { Item = "c", Value = 3 });

        listBox1.DataSource = notes;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

--
Else if you mean to use the same class as you created, then you can do it like:

```
        List<NoteView> notes = new List<NoteView>();
        notes.Add(new NoteView
        {
            a = "text one",
            b = "whatevs",
            c = "yawns"
        });

        listBox1.Items.Add(notes[0].a);
        listBox1.Items.Add(notes[0].b);
        listBox1.Items.Add(notes[0].c);
```

Comment: There is no `DataSource` available to use for ListBox in Metro apps.

Comment: Second option shows "Value does not fall within expected range" exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<NoteView> notes = new List<NoteView>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   notes.Add(new NoteView {
      a = "text one",
      b = "whatevs",
      c = "yawns"
   });
NotesList.DisplayMember = "a";
        NotesList.ValueMember = "b";
   NotesList.ItemsSource = notes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've already tried that way, too. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using WPF or Winforms. If WPF then it is different way to bind .

Comment: Xaml in Metro style application; refer to question tags. You don't get XAML in WinForms.

Comment: .net winform don't have xaml only wpf have the xaml